# VLC package dependencies broken & cannot be resolved

Tags: vlc, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. Today, suddenly some updates had arrived but it wasn't normal update. It said me to partial update. When I have done this, update manager want to remove vlc. I did it. But when I want to install vlc from synaptic package manager, I found broken dependencies there.

Now, If I want to install vlc from Software Centre, It pops up:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: fonts-freefont-ttf but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.3+git20121005+r392-0~r42~precise1) but 2.0.3+git20121005+r392-0~r42~precise1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1~precise1~ppa1 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

Hey, Now what to do?
How to resolve this problem?